# How to download pdf file in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I tried,

```
class Download extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $directory_list;
protected $fileFactory;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
DirectoryList $directory_list,
\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory) {
    $this->directory_list = $directory_list;
    $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
  //echo "pdf"; exit;
    //$file = $this->getRequest()->getParam('file');
    $file = "brochures";

    if(isset($file) && !empty($file))
    {
        $pdf = \Zend_Pdf::load($this->directory_list->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
        $fileName = 'test.pdf';
        $this->fileFactory->create(
        $fileName,
        str_replace('/Annot /Subtype /Link', '/Annot /Subtype /Link /Border[0 0 0]', $pdf->render()),
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
        'application/pdf'
          );
       }
     }
```

Getting error -

```
  error occured while '/var/www/html/test/pub/media/brochures' file reading.";i:1;s:9285:"#0 /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Pdf.php(329): Zend_Pdf_Parser->__construct('/var/www/html/h...', Object(Zend_Pdf_ElementFactory_Proxy), true)
```

Comment: This is to vague, have you check permissions are set on the directory correctly, what have you done to try and solve the issue, what are you ultimately trying to achieve (knowing this means people may know a better way)

Comment: In pub/media/brochures folder I have test.pdf file. Now in frontend I had given download brochure link. On clicking on that, it should download give path pdf file. Now it is opening of chrome browser which I dont want

Comment: I think this may just be the behavior of Chrome, or you may have an add on installed causing this https://superuser.com/questions/30850/stop-pdfs-from-displaying-inside-google-chrome